# pc program to receive data from EV3 via usb/bluetooth

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

I'm looking for a library to create a desktop program. It should receive a data from EV3 brick programmed by standard EV3 software.

Currently I consider 2 approaches:
1. EV3 brick sends a bluetooth message, PC receives it.
2. EV3 brick creates a file and writes a data to it, PC reads the file via USB.

It's more convenient for me to use USB because bluetooth is already used to connect to another brick.

I found 2 libraries how to do that, although there are obstacles:

- [monobrick C++ library](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/c-library/) - allows to read a file, but doesn't allow to connect to the brick via usb
- [Microsoft EV3 API](http://legoev3.codeplex.com/) - allows to connect to the brick via usb but doesn't allow to read a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MonoBrick C++ library that you linked is for NXT, not EV3.

You can find the MonoBrick C# Library for EV3 [here](http://www.monobrick.dk/software/monobrick/). It works with USB, Bluetooth and Wi-Fi and can manipulate files.